# Regarding polycom call setup using ISDN

Tags: video

I am using polycom HDX 7000 series VC. We used to call HQ  using the IP of their VC but now HQ wants the call setup to be done using phone number. I checked the docs for it and it says, it can be done. Can anyone help me with the configuration part of it?
Do i need to work around the gatekeeper settings?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a HDX7K I'm pretty sure you need an ISDN module to make this work, but once you've connected it, and enabled ISDN (as per the instructions in the Admin Guide) you will be given the option of the call-type on the dial window (H.323, SIP or ISDN).

It seems nuts that anyone would want to go **back** to ISDN - are you sure they don't just want you to dial via E.164 over IP via your gatekeeper?

Comment: They said that going via IP wasn't secured for them so they wanted to connect via ISDN. So, you mean we need additional ISDN module for that? Can you give me links so that i can know which and how ISDN module can be integrated in our vc.

Comment: Actually it looks like the 7K has a built-in port: http://community.polycom.com/polycom/attachments/polycom/VideoEndpoints/6231/1/HDX%20ISDN%20PRI-BRI%20Modules%20(US)%20Basic%20Provisioning%20Guide%20May%2008%202008.pdf

Comment: Hi Benjamin,i was expecting the client would not go for ISDN, but recently, they have insisted for it. I was hoping to clear certain things before hand. 1.Don't we need to get the ISDN line from the service provider?

Comment: 2.Can the ISDN line provide enough bandwidth for video conferencing and even multipoint to take place? As I understand, ISDN mean using the telephone line and instead of IP we will have to use number to contact to the other end, right? Please clearify.

Comment: Each ISDN channel will provide 64kbps for use in your VC - depending on how many channels you utilise (E1 will provide 30, T1 will provide 23) then this bandwidth can be increased (though usually at great cost and timed depending on your country).  For multipoint conferences you would generally limit each participant to (say) 256kbps (4x channels) so that there is capacity for all callers.